# IObservableVector<T> in Windows Store apps cannot be used as databinding source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have been following the [developer guidelines from MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx) to implement Data Virtualisation, which state that IObservableVector must be implemented for random access data virtualization.

I am using Reactive Extensions in a read only asynchronous implementation of `IObservableVector<T>,` which I am calling AsyncReadOnlyVirtualCollection.

When I bind a GridView to an instance of this `IObservableVector<SomeConcreteType>` then I get an exception at runtime that the type cannot be instantiated due to incompatible types with WinRT. (Unable to compute GUID for type 'Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector`1[Foo]' because the instantiation contains types that are not supported by Windows Runtime.)

If I use `*object*` instead of `*SomeConcreteType*,` which was suggested on earlier blogs when WinRT and XAML were still in CTP and framework errors were still present, then this works. Given that it is now 2015 and I am now on Windows 8.1, with the latest install of Visual Studio 2013 Community, I can only assume that I must be making some kind of error.

Why can `IObservableVector<ConcreteType>` not be used as a data source, if MS guidelines declare it must be for such databinding? If the docs are out of date, what is the correct approach?

---UPDATE---
It seems the core code that throws this error is here https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/d758145b547cc00aba3f0e3f101af27bf118e9af/src/vm/methodtable.cpp in the method BOOL MethodTable::IsLegalNonArrayWinRTType() which is applied to the generic type ConcreteType or Object above
---MORE---
OK after hacking through the above GitHub WinRT coreclr code, I see that there are checks to make sure the IObservableVector's generic type is WinRT compatible. I do not know why this is at the moment...can anyone enlighten me?

Anyway, to comply, I moved the concrete type to a new Windows Runtime Component project and added assembly references, while changing the  back to

This now "works" (the error goes away)...I now have a separate issue: The original error goes away but the Enumerator is iterated instead of indexer requested.....so not a solution after all....but WHY?

---

FURTHER UPDATE
The class works if it implements `IObservableVector<object>` not `IObservabeVector<T>`. I didn't have time to find out why, but I suspect that it has something to do with inability to cast `<T>` to `<object>`...I will post my implementation for discussion on Codeplex as I think the Rx approach is probably novel. I will update here later when this done.

Answer (score 0):

The `IObservableVector<object>` must be used for some reason. 
For interest, here is an experiment using Rx in this context
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/995043/An-experiment-with-random-access-data-virtualisati

Answer (score 0):

You say you cannot use a concrete type, so what type exactly are you using?
According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441570%28v=vs.120%29.aspx the supported types are one of the 5 listed in the "Remarks" section. Does your type comply?

Comment: I now understand the problem and experience it myself. When you use Platform::Collections::Vector<> you can use any of the complying types. If you decide to implement IObservableVector in your own class, it only works if you cast to IObservableVector<Platform::Object^>^.... I also don't know why it is like that but it also bothers me a lot.

Comment: Yeah...have a look at the link below, I managed to get all that working in a demo project with Rx